# как сделать анимацию элементов RecyclerView при onRefresh()?

Tags: java, android, анимация, recyclerview, android-viewpager

У меня есть ViewPager с тремя фрагментами, в каждом из которых свой RecyclerView. Я сделал анимацию элементов RecyclerView при фильтрации используя этот подход - [реализация фильтра с анимацией](http://365programperday.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-working-with-recyclerview-and.html)

Хотел этот же подход использовать при обновлении списка с помощью SwipeRefreshLayout методом onRefresh() внутри фрагмента:

```
onRefresh(){
    adapter.animateTo(newList);//вызов анимации 
    FragmentDriver.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
}
```

но окно со списком (RecyclerView) полностью пересоздается из-за чего анимации нет.

Как можно сделать анимацию при onRefresh()? Может быть есть другие способы?